# How to read value from database after keying in another value that is stored in the same database in C#?

Tags: c#

I am sorry if my question phrasing is off, I am not sure of how I can phrase it in a clear and proper term.

Basically I have a database with 2 columns, licenseKey and licenseType. 
I want to create a license verification page where the user enters a license (that is already stored in the database) into a textbox and then click on the Activate button.

```
LicenseKeys     License Type
xxxxxxxx        Full
yyyyyyyy        Trial
```

[image]

After the user enters the license, I would like a MessageBox to pop up and state the license type of the license entered, for example, if the user enters a license that is of a full type, the MessageBox would show ("valid full"), and show a respective message for a Trial license entered.

This is my code I have tried with:

```
private void btnActivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool tempt = false;
        string enteredkey;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connection string");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select LicenseKeys,licenseType from LicenseKeys where LicenseKeys ='" + tbLicensekey.Text + "'", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseKeys", tbLicensekey.Text);
        enteredkey = ed.Encrypt(tbLicensekey.Text);
        if (tbLicensekey.Text == enteredkey)
        {
            tempt = true;
            MessageBox.Show("valid" );
            con.Close();
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("invalid");
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

This code does not work, even if I click on the activate button without keying anything the MessageBox would display "valid".

I would like the system to work such that if I key in a wrong license, the MessageBox would show "invalid", and if I key in a correct license key, it would show "valid" and state the type of license (read from database).
Edit: I have removed the encryption and decryption codes for simplicity sake, my question is more on how I can detect the license type from the input license, not about what I am encrypting or decrypting. I put those as I am doing a security related project. Would truly appreciate a sample code as well, I can't really understand all these explanations from the comments without a visual aid. Since you all know what I did wrong, mind suggesting to me what I should do to amend the code instead of just explaining with text without any illustration? I am weak in programming here.

The database example is just a visual guide for you guys to see, the actual term in my database is LicenseKeys. How I name my database column in this question is not the main issue here. (reply to comment)

Comment: Apart from the obvious SQL Injection issues (try entering `'; delete from LicenseKeys;--` as a license key), the code compares the input to *itself*. It encrypts the input and *decrypts* the result before comparing it to itself.

Comment: You're not actually reading the data from the database...

Comment: You take entered text, encrypt it, then decrypt and compare with entered text. If decrypt/encrypt are working correctly it's always `true`.

Comment: It looks to me like it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do, you "encrypt" the entered text, then you compare the entered text to the "decrypted" value of the encrypted value, which is always equal. Anyway, you need to execute your query (cmd) at some point up there.

Comment: As David said, you aren't reading anything from the database, not even executing the query.

Comment: after `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`, the query must be submitted to the database server. adding a parameter alone does not submit the query, and the result needs to be fetched. there are many alternatives, SqlDataReader, SqlDataAdapter, ExecuteScalar to name just a few.

Comment: If the columns in your database are `License Key` and `License Type` and your query states `select LicenseKeys,licenseType`, that query won't ever run correctly.

Comment: Regarding the question edit... Now your condition will always be `false` (unless your "encryption" just returns the input).  As for your apparent frustration, we can appreciate that you're new to this and are finding it difficult, but what you're asking at this time has nothing to do with license keys. Generalize your concern a bit. You're asking how to read a value from a database and compare it with a value from user input. In order to do that you must read a value from a database. So you're asking how to read from a database. There are tutorials to get you started on exactly that....

Comment: .... It looks like you may have started with a tutorial or example, but never finished it or missed some key points in it.  Don't just copy/paste code and get frustrated.  Follow the tutorials, carefully, step by step.  Currently your code has some database-like code, but never actually reads anything from the database.  Go back to that tutorial and work on getting *just that part* functioning.  Don't worry about the rest until at least that works.

Comment: I referred to my previous school project to do my current codes. I did reading of values from database before but I used it to display data from database into listboxes for viewing purposes, not to verify like this project. There's surely a difference in reading and displaying data from database and reading and checking data from database. @David

Comment: @depressedGirl: *"a difference in reading and displaying data from database and reading and checking data from database"* - They both share one common trait... reading data from a database.  In both cases you need to debug and confirm that you are in fact successfully reading data from a database, regardless of what you plan to do with that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code snippet you shared:

- You've got the parameter `LicenseKeys`, but you're not using it in the query
- As David and Panagiotis pointed out, you're not executing the query

With those in mind, the code should probably look something like this:

```
private void btnActivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool tempt = false;
    string enteredkey;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connection string");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT licenseType FROM LicenseKeys WHERE LicenseKeys = @LicenseKeys", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseKeys", tbLicensekey.Text);
    enteredkey = ed.Encrypt(tbLicensekey.Text); // Not sure why you need the Encrpt method here
    var licenseType = cmd.ExecuteScalar<string>();
    if (licenseType != null)
    {
        tempt = true;
        MessageBox.Show("valid" + licenseType);
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("invalid");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your clear explanation, I have tried out your codes and it works just the way I want. I don't get what the <string> after ExecuteScalar stands for, but it works without me inputting that into my codes. Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry I have another question: How do I write an if statement stating that LicenseType == Trial? I have tried if (licenseType.ToString() == "Trial") but it did not work. I would like to write a slightly different MessageBox for Trial license.

Comment: The first question I can,give you for free, it's a typed method. read more on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods. Second question I'm not sure why it's not working. you'll have to be a little more apecific

Answer (score 0):

I was too slow to the answer, but I'll post this anyway as it disposes the objects...

```
private void btnActivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool tempt = false;

    string enteredkey = null; //TODO Probably encrypt here if DB value is encrypted, otherwise whats the point?
    string connectionString = @""; //TODO Set Connection String.

    string licenseKey = null; //TODO: String type?
    string licenseType = null; //TODO: String type?

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            //TODO
        }

        cmd.CommandText = @"
            SELECT LicenseKeys, licenseType
            FROM LicenseKeys
            WHERE LicenseKeys = @LicenseKeys
        ";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseKeys", enteredkey);

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    licenseKey = reader.GetString(0);
                }

                if (!reader.IsDBNull(1))
                {
                    licenseType = reader.GetString(1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO
            }
        }
    }

    tempt = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(licenseType);

    if (tempt)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format($"valid license type {licenseType}"));

        //TODO other stuff?
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("invalid"); // TODO `enter code here`

        //TODO other stuff?
    }
}
```